# Datediff formula in Crystal Report result wrong calculation

Tags: crystal-reports, datediff

Here I'm using the following formula in my crystal report to find the aging of a product. I have taken my manufacturing Date as Default_Date and Date to compare as current date.

`datediff("d",CDate({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date}),CurrentDate)`

The formula have no errors but when date is from 1st to 12th - The difference results are wrong

[image: Date compared - Current Date ie 30-07-2018]

and after 13th to 31st -

[image: Which shows correct calculation after 12th]

DOP Column date is which I'm comparing with Currentdate. A screenshot is attached

[image: D1 Column is the date which results DOP converted to Cdate and D2 is CurrentDate]

Please advice me where I'm wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which one is manufacturing Date in the report? And what is the format of Current Date? Try to debug by printing both dates, and check.

Comment: DOP column is my manufacturing date and I'm taking the current date which is of datetime format. I have edited the question in which I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: I hope you are noticing the diffrence in current_date format? Its yyyy-mm-dd, and your DOP is dd-mm-yyyy. Make sure in formula you are using both in same format.

Comment: Many Thanks @ItiTyagi. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your database field {Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date} is in DD/MM/YYYY format. CDATE does not work well with these dates. It tries to but it doesn't work very well. 
I am sure there are many different creative ways to handle this but here is my offer

```
datediff("d",
cdate(
split({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date},"/")[2]
+"/"+
split({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date},"/")[1]
+"/"+
split({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date},"/")[3]
),
currentdate
)
```

Comment: I get the following error., **A subscript must be between 1 and size of the array.**

Comment: please show me what the field {Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date} looks like without any formatiing

Comment: you bet! Have a great day

Comment: I have just altered the code like this and your offer works perfect. Many Thanks 
`datediff("d", cdate( split({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date},"-")[2] +"-"+ split({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date},"-")[1] +"-"+ split({Yarn_Packing_Weighment_Entry.Default_Date},"-")[3] ), currentdate )`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a report custom function with appropriate name in own report!

use this code to create the function

```
Function (DateTimeVar StartDate,DateTimeVar EndDate )
Local NumberVar   YY := Int(DateDiff("D", StartDate, EndDate)/365.25);
Local NumberVar   MM := Int(remainder(DateDiff("D",StartDate,EndDate),365.25)/30.4375);
Local NumberVar   DD := Int(IF(Day (EndDate) < Day(StartDate)) Then (Day(DateSerial(year(StartDate), Month(StartDate)+1,1-1)) - Day(StartDate) + Day(EndDate)) else (Day(EndDate) - Day(StartDate)));
ToText(YY, "00") & ":"&
ToText(MM, "00") & ":"&
ToText(DD, "00")


Function (DateTimeVar StartDate,DateTimeVar EndDate )
Local NumberVar   YY := Int(DateDiff("D", StartDate, EndDate)/365.25);
Local NumberVar   MM:= Int(remainder(DateDiff("D",StartDate,EndDate),365.25)/30.4375);
Local NumberVar   DD  := Int(IF(Day (EndDate) < Day(StartDate)) Then (Day(DateSerial(year(StartDate), Month(StartDate)+1,1-1)) - Day(StartDate) + Day(EndDate)) else (Day(EndDate) - Day(StartDate)));
IIF (YY > 0,ToText(YY, "00") & "eQi " ,"" ) &
IIF (MM > 0,ToText(MM, "00") & "gvm " ,"" ) &
IIF (DD > 0,ToText(DD, "00") & "w`b " ,"" )
```

there are two way has shown!